# Benefits of separating operating system files from user files onto different partitions

Tags: security, centos, hardening

I am in the process of hardening a CentOS box, and came across an article that suggested mounting these filesystems onto different partitions:

```
/usr
/home
/var and /var/tmp
/tmp
```

I was wondering what exactly this accomplishes, in terms of securing the box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a nutshell..

`/var` is where logs are stored.

`/tmp` is able to be written to by anyone.

`/home` is where user data is stored.

`/usr` is typically where software is installed.

If these locations were stored on a single filesystem, that filesystem could be fully utilized.  If `/` were full, it could potentially prevent the system from operating properly.

Additionally, separate filesystems can be mounted with different settings.  For example, I like to mount `/tmp` with `noexec` and `nosuid`.  If an application were compromised and had files written to `/tmp`, not being able to execute files would distinctly limit the ability to further compromise the system.

I would recommend reading more about the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard to better understand those locations, as my description is summarized and not complete.

- [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)
- [HIER(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/hier)
- [MOUNT(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)